# Generating Audio Fingerprint From an Audio with Echonest

Tags: algorithm, audio, audio-fingerprinting

How to generate fingerprint of an audio with [Echonest library](https://developer.echonest.com/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download `echoprint-codegen` and run

`echoprint-codegen /path/to/your/audiofile.mp3`